# How to send different data to duplicate PartialViews?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I had asked a question earlier about duplicate PartialViews and got it straightened out. Then I started thinking more about it and started wondering how am I going to populate the duplicate PartialViews with different data. I tagged this question with asp.net-mvc because its an MVC project, I was told earlier that my way is "anti-mvc", but none the less, its still an asp.net-mvc project, just minus the Razor and benefits I suppose..

Here is the situation..
I have a view that has two tabs on it, one called Manufacturer and the other Dealer, each tab has two PartialViews, one is an Address PartialView and the other is a Contact PartialView. As mentioned the Manufacturer tab has these 2 PartialViews and so does the Dealer tab.

the two PartialViews are as follows...

Address

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/Common/CommonControlsJS.js"></script>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtAddress1" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAddress1">Line 1</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="txtAddress1" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="address" placeholder="Line 1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtAddress2" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAddress2">Line 2</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="txtAddress2" type="text" class="form-control max-size" placeholder="Line 2" name="address2" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtCity" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCity">City</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="txtCity" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="city" placeholder="city" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtState" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblState">State</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="txtState" type="text" class="form-control" name="state" placeholder="state" />
        </div>
        <label for="txtZip" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblZip">Zip/Postal</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="txtZip" type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" placeholder="Zip/Postal" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="acCountries" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCountry"><b>Country</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="acCountries" class="form-control CountryDropdown" name="country"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Contact

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/Common/CommonControlsJS.js"></script>

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtContactType">Contact&nbsp;Type:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="ddContactType" name="contacttype" placeholder="ContactType" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtContact">Contact:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtContact" placeholder="Contact" name="contact" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtPhone">Home:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtPhone" placeholder="Home" name="home" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtWork">Work:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtWork" placeholder="Work" name="work" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtFax">Fax:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtFax" placeholder="Fax" name="fax" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtMobile">Mobile:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control fixed-form-control" id="txtMobile" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I know that I can populate the fields in one set of the PartialViews, but no idea how to populate the fields in with different data in the duplicates. I haven't started writing the code for it yet, as I am pondering on how to do this. Has anyone ever come across this issue? I am using JQuery Ajax to call the controller and get the returned data. There is no Razor syntax.

Is there a way to manipulate the PartialViews so I can differentiate the PartialViews from eachother? If necessary I can get the select event of each tab change, but then I am thinking of adding a custom data attribute, that is one reason of asking of being able to manipulate a PartialView.

Any idea's, direction or solutions?

**EDIT**

This is how I typically populate fields prior to using PartialViews

My AJAX

```
function GetDealerByID(getTheID) {
    var id = getTheID;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: AddURLParam.GetDealerForUpdateByDealerID + "?id=" + id,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            return DealerToUpdate(data);
        }
    })
    $("#btnAddNewDealer").attr('value', "Update");
    $("#btnDeleteNewDealer").show();
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerPassword").attr("disabled", "");
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerConfirmPassword").attr("disabled", "");
    $("#btnResetDealerPassword").show();
}
```

This calls my JsonResult

```
public JsonResult GetDealerForUpdate(int id)
    {
        try {
            Admin = new DAL.Admin();

            List<NewDealer> lst = Admin.GetDealerForUpdate(id);

            return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            EventLogger.EventSource = this.ToString() + ".GetDealerForUpdate()";
            EventLogger.PostException(Ex, EventLogger.EventSource, HttpContext.Request, HttpContext.Session,
                new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        {Functions.GetName(() => id), id.ToString() }   });
            throw new Exception(Constants.FRIENDLY_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

After I get my returned data from the controller, and my AJAX call is successful, it uses the returned data and uses this function to populate the dealer fields

```
function DealerToUpdate(dealerData) {
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerCompanyName").val(dealerData[0].dealerName);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerAddress1").val(dealerData[0].address1);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerAddress2").val(dealerData[0].address2);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerCity").val(dealerData[0].city);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerState").val(dealerData[0].state);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerZip").val(dealerData[0].zip);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerContact").val(dealerData[0].contactName);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerEmail").val(dealerData[0].email);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerPhone").val(dealerData[0].phone);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerWorkPhone").val(dealerData[0].work);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerFax").val(dealerData[0].fax);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerMobile").val(dealerData[0].mobile);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerPassword").val();
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerOther").val(dealerData[0].other);
    $("#txtAdministrationDealerUserName").val(dealerData[0].dealerLoginUserName);
    var dd = $("#acDealerCountries").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dd.text(dealerData[0].country);

    var stuff = dealerData[0].manufacturerNames;
    var myarray = stuff.split(',');

    $("#msManufacturers").getKendoMultiSelect().value(myarray);
}
```

and here is my NewDealer model that the JsonResult from the controller uses

```
public class NewDealer
    {
        public int? dealerContactID { get; set; }
        public int? dealerID { get; set; }
        public string dealerName { get; set; }
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string contactName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string work { get; set; }
        public string fax { get; set; }
        public string mobile { get; set; }
        public string other { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public int? parentID { get; set; }
        public List<string> manufacturerIDs { get; set; }
        public string manufacturerNames { get; set; }
        public string dealerLoginUserName { get; set; }
    }
```

I chose to now use PartialViews to cut down on duplicate code

Comment: "Duplicate" implies that the views are the same, which doesn't seem to be the case here. Is the data for each view coming from one model?

Comment: @TiesonT., thats a good question...I think that the JsonResult methods would come from the same controller and populate 2 different JQuery objects that would be used to populate the fields. For the model, I would have two seperate models, one for the Manufacturer and the other for the Dealer and they would have their own seperate objects in JavaScript

Comment: So, are your tabs just UI elements, for showing one panel or the other, or is there a "current" panel that gets reloaded whenever your user chooses a "tab"?

Comment: Its Boostrap tabs, so whichever tab gets clicked it class gets set as "active". Other than the partialviews, there is also a grid in each tab that has Manufacturer records or Dealer records, which is dependent on which tab you are in. So if I am in the Manufacturer tab and click Manufacturer A from the Manufacturer grid then the partialviews will populate with that data

Comment: Why do you not want to use a model and the `HtmlHelper` methods which will generate the correct html for you and allow you to bind to your model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Hi there, for some reason I knew you would make your way to this question, you helped me out earlier. I'm the "anti mvc"

Comment: Why don't you use an Ajax GET method instead of JSON Result. Populate the entire form based on the selection?

Comment: If you were to simply use an `EditorTemplate` for `Address` and another for `ContactDetails` and use a model with properties (say) `ManufacturerAddress` and `ManufacturerContactDetails` (ditto for Dealer) and in the view `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ManufacturerAddress)` etc, it would generate the correct html that allows you to have 2-way binding to your model (and add client and server side validation)

Comment: @progrAmmar, I am using an AJAX GET method, it calls my JsonResult method. If select a record and populate the entire form then both the manufacturer and Dealer Address and Contact partialviews will populate with the data, and I only want one set of partialviews to populate based on what tab I am in

Comment: @Chris You already have partial views, set your JsonResult to ActionResult and in your controller, call the desired PartialView (populated with the model). Set your Ajax content to html. It will return the HTML for the desired PartialView (populated with data) which you can append to the tab div. Can you post your cshtml for the views and the controller actions you are calling?

Comment: @progrAmmar, I am a little confused. I made an edit and added code on how I was doing things prior to using PartialViews. With what I just provided is it possible to show me what you are talking about?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I think the next project that is started from scratch I'll be more apt to push to not be "anti mvc" ;) the deeper this project gets it looks more complex the way that its being done and probably would have been a 100 times easier the other way. You live you learn ;)

Comment: @Chris so from your comments I gather that you have different sections of record, you want to show Address separately (in separate partial view and you want to show Contact in separate partial view) correct? Ant these are shown in TABS right? please confirm so I may provide a solution

Comment: @progrAmmar, that is correct. The manufacturer tab has the Address and Contact partialview and the Dealer tab uses the exact same partialviews. My assumption is that if the Address and Contact partialviews in the Manufacturer tab get populated then since the Dealer tab has the same partialviews, that they would also get populated as well and that can and will cause problems.

Comment: @Chris and you only plan to populate the data only if the tab is clicked

Comment: @progrAmmar, no. Each tab has a grid with records in it, the only time that the fields get populated is when a record/row is selected from the grid

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am suggesting.

You can use Razor in your Partial Views. Create two new ViewModels Address and Contact

On the Grid of records for Manufacturers and Dealers on the row add a data- attribute

```
<tr class="record" data-id="@manufacturerid" data-type="manufacturer"> x x x x x x x </tr>
```

Similarly for your dealer record

```
<tr class="record" data-id="@dealerid" data-type="dealer"> x x x x x x x </tr>
```

Have a div to display the form

```
<div id='addressDiv' style="display:none"></div>
<div id='contactDiv' style="display:none"></div>
```

In your controller add two new Methods getting the data and contact:

```
public ActionResult GetAddress(int id, string type)
{
        //Get Address fields based on id and type
        AddressViewModel model = new AddressViewModel();
        //Populate the model with the data

        return PartialView("_AddressPartial", model);
}
public ActionResult GetContact(int id, string type)
{
        //Get contact fields based on id and type
        ContactViewModel model = new ContactViewModel();
        //Populate the model with the data

        return PartialView("_ContactPartial", model);
}
```

Now change your onclick function

```
$('.record').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type);
    $('#addressDiv').empty();
    $('#contactDiv').empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "http://someurl/Controller/GetAddress",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { id: id, type: type },
        contentType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#addressDiv').append(result);
            $('#addressDiv').show();
            // Bind your editing div event functions here
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "http://someurl/Controller/GetContact",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { id: id, type: type },
        contentType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#contactDiv').append(result);
            $('#contactDiv').show();
            // Bind your editing div event functions here
        }
    });

});
```

This method will allow you to get minimum data (only the required fields) and you get your partial views functionality

Comment: Great, do comment after testing it, if it worked or not.